# Understanding Arrow Function Behavior with Conditional Operations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax, arrow-functions

I'm learning arrow functions in JavaScript and attempting to conditionally set the value of show to false based on a certain value. While using the '&&' operator for this purpose, I encountered a syntax issue with the following code:

```
const obCallback = (something) =>
    something.value === 1
    && show = false;
```

I know it works when I do this:

```
const obCallback = (something) => {
    if (something.value === 1) {
        show = false;
    }
};
```

or this:

```
const obCallback = (something) => something.value === 1 ? show = false : undefined;
```

Can anyone of you please explain why the first code snippet doesn't work and the other do? Can we only do function calls but not assignments after "&&" in an arrow function, because the below seems to be working?

```
const obCallback = (something) =>
    something.value === 1
    && Dance(); //This works
```

I know this seems like a basic question but I'm seeking a thorough explanation to improve my understanding of using arrow functions in the future.

Comment: The first code snippet doesn't work because it's not really checking anything. All it's doing is getting a boolean representation of something.value === 1   What then happens it is runs show = false and then ends there.

Comment: To make it work as you are probably expecting, you just need to turn it it into a turnary operator like such: const obCallback = (something) => (shomething.value === 1 ? show = false : show = true);

Comment: My money is on operator precedence, `(show = false);`

Comment: alternatively, if you don't want to have the show = true, just type null and nothing will happen

Comment: @Barmar true, removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` has lower precedence than `===` and `&&`, so your expression is being parsed as

```
const obCallback = (something) =>
    (something.value === 1
    && show) = false;
```

which is invalid because you can't assign to an expression. Add parentheses to force the intended grouping

```
const obCallback = (something) =>
    something.value === 1
    && (show = false);
```

That said, most programmers think it's poor form to use logical operators in place of control flow. Use an `if` statement for this.